# Why commands executed inside backticks doesn't affect the current shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I know that backticks are used for command substitution, but why doesn't those commands affect the current shell. For example, executing the following command changes my current working directory to the previous directory I was in.

```
$> cd -
```

On the other hand, the following command does show me contents of my previous working directory but doesn't change it.

```
$> ls `cd -`
```

Similarly, there could be other examples like

```
$>ls `PATH=""`
```

Here, it does shows the contents of my working directory but the `PATH` variable doesn't get changed.

Is the command / expression inside backticks executed in a sub-shell?

Answer (score 2):

It works like `eval(exp)` in some of the programming languages:

it is evaluated in an external scope, which is a "child" of the current scope (also called [subshell](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html) environment) - so it "knows" all the vars in the current env, and returns only the result - hence, can't cause any side-effect to the current environment.

Backticks is an old-style and `$()` should be used instead. To read more info about command substitution - see [the docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03)

Comment: Is there any way i can verify whether a sub-shell is created ?

Comment: echo the variable `$$` which is the process id.

Comment: @MarkSetchell `$BASH_PID`. A subshell will have the same `$$`.

Comment: Your link does not indicate that backticks are deprecated.

Comment: @ThomasDickey bad wording on my side - I meant "to read more about command substitution" not about the fact that backtics are deprecated. But now that you mentioned it - I added a relevant link to that as well. Thanks!

Comment: @alfasin, The http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete is not an authoritative body/source and has no control over the standards.  The use of backticks are still present in the current official documentation of the GUN BASH Shell and without any notation to it being official depreciation as it just hasn't happened **yet**.  It is also still a part of the source code and binary bash executable.  Granted the `$()` Command Substitution is the preferred method in use today and the use of backticks is the _old-style_ and or _legacy_ method, yet it hasn't **yet** been officially depreciated.

Comment: @user3439894 I stand corrected, the wording has changed respectively - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Subshells have a different `$BASHPID`'s--they're `fork`ed off the original shell.

```
$ echo $BASHPID; echo "`echo $BASHPID`"; echo $BASHPID
```

When you fork on Unix, the child process copy-on-write inherits (or just inherits by eager copying) data from the parent process.
The child process (the subshell) can read all the variables, but writing to any of those will create a private copy for the child (or it already has its own copy if the kernel doesn't do the copy-on-write thing).